# Find minimal polynomial of $ \alpha = \zeta_5 + i \sqrt[4]{5}$ over $\mathbb {Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm having some trouble finding the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha = \zeta_5 + i \sqrt[4]{5}$  over $\mathbb {Q}$,  where $\zeta_5$ is the fifth root of 1 ($\zeta_5 := e^{\frac{2\pi}{5}i}$).

I know that $\mathbb {Q}(\zeta_5)\supset$ $\mathbb {Q}(\sqrt[]{5})$ and obviously $(\sqrt[4]{5})^2=\sqrt[]{5}$. 
Any idea?

Comment: Can you describe the conjugates of $\alpha$ ? How many are there ?

Comment: No, what you just said is completely wrong. Okay, let us proceed more slowly : do you know the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$ ? Of $i\sqrt[4]{5}$ ? (the two parts in $\alpha$).

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$ is $ x^4+x^3+^x^2+x+1 $, for $i\sqrt[4]{5}$ is $x^4+5$

Comment: Yeah, a little mistake, i corrected it

Comment: Right. Now, tell me the value of $(\alpha-\zeta_5)^4+5$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104328/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-saber98).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CORRECTION**: All thanks to მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, for disbelieving a “simplification” that I had erroneously made. The very slightly corrected posting follows, giving a radically different final result.

Let me contribute an approach different to that of Nguyen Quang Do. I’ll write $\zeta$ for $\zeta_5$.
We know that the field $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5\,)=\Bbb Q(\zeta,i\sqrt[4]5\,)$ is quartic over $k=\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$, in fact biquadratic, the compositum of the quadratic extensions $k(\zeta)$ and $k(i\sqrt[4]5\,)$ of $k$.

First, let’s find the minimal polynomial of $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ over $k$; this is the most work.

Now,
\begin{align}
\text{Irr}\bigl(\zeta,k[x]\bigr)&=x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt5}2x+1=f(x)&(1)\\
\text{Irr}\bigl(\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5,k(\sqrt[4]5\,)[x]\bigr)&=f(x-i\sqrt[4]5\,)
=g(x)\in k(\sqrt[4]5\,)[x]\,.
\end{align}
The relation $(1)$ is easily found, and I’ll leave the work to you. Next step is to form $\overline g(x)$ by replacing $i\sqrt[4]5$ by $\overline{i\sqrt[4]5}=-i\sqrt[4]5$, and multiplying to get $g\overline g=h(x)$. This is
$$
h(x)=\frac{7 - \sqrt5}2 -4x + \frac{7 +3\sqrt5}2x^2 + (1 - \sqrt5)x^3 + x^4\,,
$$
equal to the minimal polynomial for $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ over $k$. Notice that its coefficients are $k$-integers, a reassuring observation.

Finally, form $\overline h(x)$ by replacing $\sqrt5$ by $-\sqrt5$, and multiply:
\begin{align}
\text{Irr}\bigl(\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5, \Bbb Q[x]\bigr)&=h(x)\overline h(x)\\&=
11 - 28x + 48x^2 - 26x^3 + 14x^5 + 3x^6 + 2x^7 + x^8\,.
\end{align}
This result is the same as that of მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, as appears in one of their comments. Once again, I give thanks for the disbelief.

Comment: But is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ the same? I believe it is different.

Comment: And I, @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, believe it is the same. After all, the minimal polynomial for $i\sqrt[4]5$ over $k$ is $x^2+\sqrt5$, while that for $\sqrt[4]5$ is $x^2-\sqrt5$. Since, in the last step, we multiplied $h_{\sqrt5}(x)$ times its conjugate $h_{-\sqrt5}(x)=\overline h(x)$, we should have at this stage also caught $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ as a root. (This is not a proof, just a plausibility argument. It’s too late at night here for me to actually substitute the quantity of interest into my $h\overline h$.)

Comment: I now substituted $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ in the polynomial and, if I am not mistaken, it is not zero. It might be that I fail to simplify the radicals but I also evaluated it numerically in Mathematica and it is about $-1748.66-1451.72i$

Comment: In fact,$$h_1(x):=f(x-i\sqrt[4]5)f(x+i\sqrt[4]5)=\frac{7-\sqrt5}2-4x+\frac{7+3\sqrt5}2x^2+(1-\sqrt5)x^3+x^4,$$and if $\bar h_1(x)$ is obtained from $h_1(x)$ by replacing $\sqrt5$ with $-\sqrt5$ throughout, then for $h_1(x)\bar h_1(x)$ I get$$11-28 x+48 x^2-26 x^3+14 x^5+3 x^6+2 x^7+x^8.$$ This is zero on $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$, if I am not making some mistake.

Comment: Troubled by the discrepancy between $\zeta+\sqrt 5$ and $\zeta+i\sqrt 5$, I checked again  ... and found an error! Actually $k(\zeta i\sqrt [4] 5)/k$ is *not* quadratic. If I adapt my proof and replace $k=\mathbf Q(i)$ by $k=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$, then everything rolls and I recover @Lubin's variant $K=\mathbf Q(\zeta+\sqrt [4] 5)$. But now $k(i)$ is not contained in $K$ (we know the quadratic subextensions of $K/k$), so $K(i)/k$ is triquadratic and contains the extension $L=\mathbf Q(\zeta+i\sqrt [4] 5)$ of the OP. In fact $K$ and $L$ are conjugate in $K(i)$.

Comment: It’s morning now here, in Minnesota, and time for me to eat crow. The complaints of @მამუკაჯიბლაძე are fully justified. I will redo the computation, correctly this time. But I have some personal business to take care of first.

Comment: @Lubin Curiously enough, your polynomial is also minimal for $\zeta^2+i\sqrt[4]5$, while mine is also minimal for $\zeta^2+\sqrt[4]5$

Comment: That’s not curious at all,@მამუკაჯიბლაძე. I realized, tossing and turning in bed last night, that since both $\zeta+\sqrt[4]5$ and $\zeta+i\sqrt[4]5$ are in the normal field $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]5,\zeta_5)$, and both are quadratic over $L=\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]5\,)$, any automorphism that takes $\sqrt[4]5$ to $i\sqrt[4]5$ will necessarily take $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ to $\zeta^2+\zeta^3$.

Answer (score 3):

The most natural method (not necessarily the most economical) to compute the minimal polynomial over a base field of an algebraic element $\alpha$ is to compute its conjugates and use their symmetric functions. Let me outline it in your example, for $\alpha=\zeta_5 +i\sqrt [4] 5$ over $\mathbf Q$. This is actually a disguised exercise in Galois theory.

First define $k=\mathbf Q (i)$ and determine $K=k(\alpha)$. Introduce the biquadratic  (i.e. galois with group $G\cong C_2 \times C_2$) extension $L=k(\zeta_5, i\sqrt [4] 5)$, whose 3 quadratic subextensions are $k(\zeta_5), k(i\sqrt [4] 5), k(\zeta_5 i\sqrt [4] 5)$. It is easy to show that the $G$-conjugates of $\alpha$ over $k$ are the primitive elements of $K/k$, see e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325514/300700. This shows that $L=K$ and gives the symmetric functions of $\alpha$ over $k$, hence its minimal polynomial $f_k (X)$ over $k$, of degree 4.

To get the minimal polynomial $f_{\mathbf Q} (X)$ of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q$, it suffices to compute the conjugate $g_k (X)$ of $f_k (X)$ under the complex conjugation which generates Gal($k/\mathbf Q$), to obtain finally $f_{\mathbf Q} (X)=f_k (X)g_k (X)$ .

*Erratum*: See the discussion below

Comment: Thank you, that was a misprint, k=Q(i) actually.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know much about this method, particularly on symmetric function. Could you give me some pdf?

Answer (score 2):

*Erratum: To be reclassified as a comment. I don't know how to proceed.*

The elementary symmetric functions $s_i$ of the roots $t_j$ of a polynomial are defined in any course in algebra, see e.g. Lang's book. The most well known are the trace and norm. Up to signs, they give the coefficients of the polynomial. More precisely, if $f(X)=(X-t_1)...(X-t_n)$, then $f(X)=X^n-s_1x^{n-1}+...+(-1)^n s_n$, with $s_1=t_1+...+t_n$ (trace), $s_2=\sum t_i t_j,..., s_n=t_1...t_n$ (norm). The word "symmetric" has an obvious origin.

Answer (score 2):

Troubled by the discrepancy between $\zeta+\sqrt 5$ and $\zeta+i\sqrt 5$, I checked again  ... and found an error! Actually $k(\zeta i\sqrt [4] 5)/k$ is *not* quadratic. If I adapt my proof and replace $k=\mathbf Q(i)$ by $k=\mathbf Q(\sqrt 5)$, then everything rolls and I recover @Lubin's variant $K=\mathbf Q(\zeta+\sqrt [4] 5)$. But now $k(i)$ is not contained in $K$ (we know the quadratic subextensions of $K/k$), so $K(i)/k$ is triquadratic and contains the extension $L=\mathbf Q(\zeta+i\sqrt [4] 5)$ of the OP. In fact $K$ and $L$ are conjugate in $K(i)$.

Comment: PS: I made again an error of manipulation and posted this comment as ananswer !! Please  consider this "new answer" as being deleted.